# bash - For every file in a directory, copy it into another directory, only if it doesn't exists there already

Tags: bash

Thank you very much in advance for helping!

I have a directory with some html files

```
$ ls template/content/html
devel.html
idex.html
devel_iphone.html
devel_ipad.html
```

I'd like to write a bash function to copy every file in that folder into a new location (introduction/files/), ONLY if a file with the same name doesn't exist already there.

This is what I have so far:

```
orig_html="template/content/html";
dest_html="introduction/files/";

function add_html {
    for f in $orig_html"/*";
    do
        if [ ! -f SAME_FILE_IN_$dest_html_DIRECTORY ];
        then
            cp $f $dest_html;
        fi
    done
}
```

The capital letters is where I was stuck.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The `rsync` tool is specialized to do exactly this task, even for local-to-local copies assuming you don't necessarily need to use bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would the -n option be enough for your needs?

```
   -n, --no-clobber
          do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)
```

Answer (score 2):

use rsync like this:

```
rsync -c -avz --delete $orig_html $dest_html
```

which keep $orig_html indentical with $dest_html based file checksum.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a bash script ? `cp` supports the -r (recursive) option, and the -u (update) option. From the man page:

```
   -u, --update
      copy only when the SOURCE file is  newer  than  the  destination
      file or when the destination file is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$f` variable contains the full path, because of the `/*`.
Try doing something like:

```
for ff in $orig_html/*
  do
    thisFile=${ff##*/}
    if [ ! -f ${dest_html}/$thisFile ]; then
       cp $ff ${dest_html}
    fi
  done
```